# Show negative values in stacked chart (amchart)

Tags: javascript, amcharts

In the following example, the value of X=X1+X2+X3, and I want to show negative X3 below the zero axis. Also, when computing the percentage value, it appears that negative value of X3 is not taken into account. For example, for year 2001, percentage values for X1, X2, and X3 are computed as 70, 20, and  -10, respectively. However, I want these to be (100*(70/(70+20-10)) % (87.5 %), (100*(20/(70+20-10)) % (25%), and (100*(-10/(70+20-10)) % (-12.5 %), respectively.

example here: https://jsfiddle.net/831g79xp/1/

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "marginRight":30,
    "legend": {
        "equalWidths": false,
        "periodValueText": "total: [[value.sum]]",
      "valueText": "[[value]] ([[percents]]%)",
        "position": "top",
        "valueAlign": "left",
        "valueWidth": 100
    },
    "dataProvider": [
{
        "year": 2001,
        "X1": 70,
        "X2": 20,
        "X3": -10,
     }, {
         "year": 2002,
   "X1": 80,
        "X2": 15,
        "X3": -20,
    }, {
        "year": 2003,
    "X1": 90,
        "X2": 20,
        "X3": -25,
    }],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "regular",
        "gridAlpha": 0.07,
        "position": "left",
        "title": "X Components"
    }],
    "graphs": [{
         "balloonText":"<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.6,
        "lineAlpha": 0.4,
        "title": "X1",
        "valueField": "X1"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.6,
        "lineAlpha": 0.4,
        "title": "X2",
        "valueField": "X2"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.6,
        "lineAlpha": 0.4,
        "title": "X3",
        "valueField": "X3"
    }
],
    "plotAreaBorderAlpha": 0,
    "marginTop": 10,
    "marginLeft": 0,
    "marginBottom": 0,
    "chartScrollbar": {},
    "chartCursor": {
        "cursorAlpha": 0
    },
    "categoryField": "year",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "startOnAxis": true,
        "axisColor": "#DADADA",
        "gridAlpha": 0.07,
        "title": "Year" 
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
     }
});
```

Comment: Mixing of positive and negative numbers in stacked area charts is not supported in amCharts. Consider using stacked columns instead.

Comment: Thanks @martynasma. I will follow your suggestion.